# Set height 100% to absolute div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, absolute

I have a sidebar menu:

HTML

```
<div class="container right-menu">
    <nav class="panel-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about us">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.right-menu {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.panel-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 195px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 87px 0 0 21px;
    margin-right: -59px;
    background: #f6f6f3;
    box-shadow: inset 7px 0 5px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I need to do to `panel-nav` was the full height of the page. But now, this div has a height equal to the height of the contents inside. How to fix it?

Comment: It's a absolute positioned DIV, why float, padding and margin? Set the top and left instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by simply changing height from `100%` to `100vh` of parent div:

```
.right-menu {
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rycpx4g2/

`vh` is a CSS3 measurement unit that stands for `viewport height`

Answer (score 1):

You can set `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` at the absolute position element in order to achieve 100% height according to the relative positioned parent element:

```
.panel-nav {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can use jQuery and set a new top position to `.panel-nav` every time you scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.panel-nav').css({'top': top + 'px'});
});
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <ul>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Wrong. If you scroll the window.

Comment: You should explain that you want to preserve 100% height on scroll

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bek9L/1879/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <p>This is a side bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean condimentum.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container{
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
.content{
    width:75%;
    margin-left:25%;
}
.sidebar{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background:gray;
}
```

Comment: You can place your content in a container!

Answer (score 1):

Here problem is with height, to solve it add height of html and body to 100%

i.e

```
html,body{
        height:100%;
         padding:0;
          margin:0;
    }
```

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/03mjryjw/1/

Answer (score 0):

When using `position: absolute;` you won't be setting `height` values.

You should be using `top: 0, bottom: 0;` to achieve a 100% height.

If you want to make sure that this does not change when the window is scrolled, use `position: fixed;`

Comment: Wrong. Try to scroll down ;)

Comment: The sidebar wont scroll with the page with position fixed. But its a simple solution.

Comment: They didn't specify they wanted to scroll too. Adding height: 100% fix?

Answer (score 0):

Use this way very easy
Step 1 make a hole div and put a content using padding-right only
step 2 inside make a one more div set a position:fixed; and also set a height and color

check a code and easy to do this `enter code here`
http://jsfiddle.net/simeon1929/h3sqe9re/15/